# Transparent row colours in tabularx environment using XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color, tabularx, transparency

I'm trying to build a table with alternating row colours, with one of the colours slightly transparent. I have the table layout working as intended, however I cannot figure out a way to get the row colours to be transparent. As far as I can tell, the `transparent` package will not work, as it does not work with XeLaTeX (I am also using the `fontspec` package, which requires XeLaTeX). The following is the MWE of what I have so far

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{rtable}{mm}%
    {\rowcolors{2}{}{gray!50}\tabularx{\columnwidth}{c L}%
    \bfseries{#1} & \bfseries{#2}\\%
    }
    {\endtabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{document}
\begin{rtable}{label 1}{label 2}
1 & this is a test\\
2 & to see if this works
\end{rtable}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

However this obviously has no transparency. The full document has a background which I would like to show through the row shading. While I'm aware that it makes it easier to use transparency, I would prefer to avoid using the Tikz `matrix` package, as that opens a whole 'nother can of worms with getting the table cells to be the right size.

Comment: Just a suggestion: what about mixing the row colour with the background colour via the colour functions of xcolor?

Comment: While it's a good idea in theory, the background has a texture to it, which would be impossible to merge/mix in the way you're suggesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the tikz commands, but as transparency doesn't respect groups and also affect the text, there is a certain amount of setting and resetting involved:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{extbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx,tikz}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{rtable}{mm}%
    {\rowcolors{2}{}{gray!50}\tabularx{\columnwidth}{c L}%
    \bfseries{#1} & \bfseries{#2}\\%
    }
    {\endtabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\begin{document}

\begin{rtable}{label 1}{label 2}
1 & this is a test\\
2 & to see if this works
\end{rtable}


\begin{rtable}{label 1}{label 2}
\noalign{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}%
\pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
1\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}& 
\leavevmode \pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
this is a test\\
2 & to see if this works
\end{rtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, I should be able to use that.